# Compass struck while executing 'rake install'

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, octopress

I'm trying octopress with GitHub to host some html files. Everything is fine until `rake generate` command which generates the public folder as mentioned in Octopress documentation. But, when I execute `rake watch` command it shows the following and does nothing after these lines. I've stopped it and reinstalled everything but it works the same. Any ideas?

```
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass.
Configuration from /home/blackknight/octopress/_config.yml
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
[2013-10-19 15:41:24] regeneration: 94 files changed
Change detected at 15:41:24 to: screen.scss
identical public/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley

Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rake watch` command is doing exactly what you asked it to: watching your source files for changes and regenerating them as necessary.  And even though it looks like Compass is doing something you should wait for, it's really waiting for you to do something!  Try editing a blog post or the layout and saving your changes and you should see something like:

`[2013-12-18 00:20:18] regeneration: 1 files changed`

Keep in mind too that the `rake preview` command will also have the last line of `Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.` but your preview server will be running and your site viewable at `http://localhost:4000` or `http://localhost:4000/ProjectName` if you're using a Github Project Page